# How do I make a specific user view their own text files in JFileChooser? JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to set my code up for when a certain student logs in, that they will be able to view their own grade. I thought the way I currently have my code set up that each student will be able to view their own grade. However, no matter which student logs in, they can view all the text files that are in the current directory which I do not want. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

[image: First student is logged in (should only see hw 1)]

[image: Student 2 is logged in (shouldn't be able to see hw1, but does)]

```
  // student text file, this opens the StudentPassword.txt file
            StudentPassFile studacc = new StudentPassFile();
            studacc.openFile();
            studacc.read_file();

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("View Grades");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (StudentPassFile.map.get(AccountLogin.user) != null && StudentPassFile.map.get(AccountLogin.user).equals(AccountLogin.passw)) // IF STUDENT ACCOUNT
            {
                AccountLogin.currentAccount = AccountLogin.user;
                StudentPassFile.password = AccountLogin.passw;



            FileSystemView fsv = new DirectoryRestrictedFileSystemView(new File("Grades"));
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(fsv.getHomeDirectory(),fsv);
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String nameFile = f.getAbsolutePath();

            try {

                FileReader reader = new FileReader(nameFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                jTextArea1.read(br, null);
                br.close();
                jTextArea1.requestFocus();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }


        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about creating a custom file filter that only accepts the student's file? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters

Comment: Is there another way? I am not quite following that article that you provided.

Comment: do you want a real secure way or just some way ... because if the files are physically there - you can only do this with administration, java is too late in this. If you have a client server environment you have a chance to do something with permissions, but this way the effort looks worthless

Comment: I just want some way in doing this honestly.

Comment: `I just want some way in doing this honestly.` - So why are you displaying a file chooser? If the user logs in you should know which file contains the grades that are specifically related to him. So just read the file.